# Database performance transactions vs comparisons

Tags: database, performance

this is probably a beginners question but i want to know what has a better performance in a database.
If i just delete a lot of records and insert them again with a few changes or look up where the changes are via comparisons and only do transactions for them. Every transaction is logged in the Background.

Thanks in advance